# val() returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my script

```
<input type="text" id="teamleader-default" value="${foo.teamLeaderId}/${foo.teamLeaderFirstName} ${foo.teamLeaderLastName}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var teamleader = $('#teamleader-default').val();
var tl_details = teamleader.split("/");

$('#teamleader-default').prop('type', 'hidden');

$("#update").submit(function() {

    if ($('#ParentDD :selected').text() == "Engineer") {
        var tmp0 = $('#teamleader').val(tl_details[1]);
        var tmp1 = $('#teamleaderId').val(tl_details[0]);
        alert(tmp0);
        alert(tmp1);
    } else {
        var tmp2 = $('#teamleader').val('');
        var tmp3 = $('#teamleaderId').val(0);
        alert(tmp2);
        alert(tmp3);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is that I can't assign a value for both the teamleader and the teamleader ID

```
        $('#teamleader').val(tl_details[1]);
        $('#teamleaderId').val(tl_details[0]);
```

instead the value it contains is just saying "Object object" like the one in this image:

[image]

Can anyone help me on how to assign a value for the team leader.

Again a big thanks for those who could help me.

Comment: a tip for you, in the future try to simplify the problem (question) and make more generic, this will help you to reach more people and reaching more people get easier to get a answer.

Comment: Thanks Jon, will surely remember that tip

Comment: What does `tl_details` log in the console?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(tl_details)`?

Comment: Your value is an object. When put in an alert box like that, it is converted to a string which simply tells you it was an object. Instead, try `console.log(tmp0)` and you can inspect it in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: What do You get for tl_details?

Comment: from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) `val(avalue)` return jQuery Object, not the value setted . it allow chaining function call on the same jQuery Object

Comment: @Hacketo Good catch.

Comment: @somethinghere, only if used as getter, i.e. without params :-)

Comment: @somethinghere
@Vucko
@dansasu11
the value i get from `console.log(tl_details)` is `["1", "Raymond Esguerra"]`

@dsh
the value i get from `console.log(tm0)` is `[context: document, selector: "#teamleader"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments above have already answered the question quite well, if you want to know whether it is assgined successfully, you can use `tm0.val()`.

By the way, using alert is not my choice to debug code like Js. Since you have chosen Chrome, you can get the advanced debug tool just press `F12`.You can get some tips on [How to use Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Happy coding~

Comment: Its true, though it might be better to elaborate a bit on the fact that `val(arg)` does _not_ return the value but an object, which explains the `[object Object]` Also it wouldnt be bad to mention the commenter: Hacketo.

Comment: @somethinghere Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @somethinghere
how can i send the values of tl_details[0] and tl_details[1]
to a input type hidden?

Comment: @Mikael1 Just use `val()` in the same way. See this question if you are wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289397/jquery-change-value-of-hidden-input-field